# Dynamically search for null in sqlite select query using python

Tags: python, sqlite, null, sql-injection

I'm new to python and I want to do a similar query to this one:

```
_c.execute('select * from cases where bi = ? and age = ? and 
            shape = ? and margin = ? and density = ?',(obj['bi'], 
            obj['age'], obj['margin'], obj['density']))
```

When some of the parameters are `None`, for example `obj['bi'] = None`, the query searches for the row when `bi = 'None'`. But I want it to search for the row when: `'bi is NULL'`

A possible solution is to verify the values of the parameters one by one in a sequence of if-elses. For example:

```
query = 'select * from cases where'

if obj['bi'] is None:
   query += ' bi is null'
else:
   query += ' bi = ' + str(obj['bi']) + ' and '
    ...
# do the same if-else for the other parameters
    ...

_c.execute(query)
```

But, it doesn't seem to me as the best solution. 
The question is, what is the best solution to the given problem and how to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: `(CASE WHEN ?1 = 'None' THEN bi IS NULL ELSE bi = ?1 END) AND ...`?

Comment: @Shawn What is `?1`? I don't know this syntax

Comment: It's the first bound parameter. `?2` is the second, and so on. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam

Comment: @Shawn 3 years of using SQLite and never once encountered that. Thanks. I suggest you answer the question if you think you can solve the problem; it's not a trivial-answer-in-commments type of problem

Comment: @Shawn could you please explain more your idea?

Comment: It was an idea that turned out to not be needed, but basically check to see if the parameter is equal to a particular value and do different comparisons based on that, with the same parameter being used in multiple places in the expression. (Using a numbered or named placeholder lets you do that like it's a normal variable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after firing up a python REPL and playing around with it a bit, it's simpler than I thought. The Python sqlite bindings turn a Python `None` into a SQL `NULL`, not into a string `'None'` like it sounded like from your question. In SQL, `=` doesn't match `NULL` values, but `IS` will. So...

Given a table `foo` looking like:

```
a     | b
--------------
NULL  | 1
Dog   | 2
```

Doing:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a IS ?', (None,))
print(c.fetchone())
```

will return the `(NULL, 1)` row, and

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a IS ?', ('Dog',))
print(c.fetchone())
```

will return the `('Dog', 2)` row.

In other words, use `IS` not `=` in your query.